# Gallery images not displaying in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, slimbox

I have a problem which I do not know how to solve. I have a gallery using slimbox on my website. It works great in Firefox and other browsers (on both Windows and Mac), but the images are not visible, and are no longer links, when viewed in Internet Explorer 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `display:none;` in your `.mosaic-backdrop` class. It get's overidden in Chrome/FF but not in IE.

Remove it.

Comment: Thanks mate. That did it. Can you solve other 2 mysteris?? My images are now displayed but they are not links, and hence my gallery doesn't work. On mouse over, title should show up, and clicking should work, but nothing happen. Again this problem is only IE9 related. Can you help me to solve this as well??

Comment: Your images aren't 'links' in FF/Chrome either, your <a> tag surrounds  <div>/<h4> tags which pop-up a product title that you then click. 

If you need your image to be a link it should be enclosed within <a> tags but I don't think this is what you want anyway.

Add "display:block;" in place of the "display:none;" you removed earlier.

Comment: I did that, but nothing change. h4 tag stil does not arise to be used as link. Any idea what may cause this? Thanks in advance for your help, i appreciate it very much.

Comment: I can't look right now but when i get some free time i'll dig a little deeper