# slim box image gallery doesnt work in ie9

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, slimbox

I'm using [slimbox2](http://www.digitalia.be/software/slimbox2) to create a [image gallery](http://www.georgiadis.biz/newsite/creations.php). It currently works great on Firefox and other browsers, but in IE9 the hidden div does is not displayed, causing the image titles to not be clickable and the gallery to break. I don't know if this is a problem in earlier versions of IE.

[The gallery](http://www.georgiadis.biz/newsite/creations.php)

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Sure you didn't put some necessary things for IE9 inside this proprietary comment for IE versions *below* 9? "*if lt IE 9*"

Comment: possible duplicate of [gallery doesn't work in IE9, images not displayed. workd great in FF, on both win and mac](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10554596/gallery-doesnt-work-in-ie9-images-not-displayed-workd-great-in-ff-on-both-wi)